# How to make a github action run on a cron schedule

Tags: github, cron, github-actions

I have the following github action that is not working:

```
name: Scheduled Cypress Tests

on:
  schedule:
    # Runs at 8:20am UTC every day (see https://crontab.guru)
    - cron: '20 8 * * *'
jobs:
  cypress-tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x]
    container:
      image: cypress/browsers:node16.5.0-chrome94-ff93
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: setup node ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - name: install packages with yarn
        uses: Borales/actions-yarn@v3
      - run: yarn test:components
```

I expected this to run at 8:20am UTC (4:20am EST) however it did not run (and while this action shows up in the actions list, there is literally no executed jobs for it there) and the same job runs fine when attached to a PR so I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: I don't see any obvious syntax errors, but check in the Actions tab on your repo to be sure the workflow file is not invalid.  Also scheduled runs are sometimes delayed — did it run eventually?

Comment: A minor detail is that 8 am UTC is 3 am EST (UTC-05), not 4 am.  Eastern Time is currently in EDT (UTC-04) though, so 4 am EDT / ET.  https://time.is/ET

Comment: Update: I found your repo here and it looks like the workflow is now running successfully.  https://github.com/ryanzec/monorepo-template/actions/workflows/scheduled-cypress-tests.yaml